# Postresql SQL State: 25P02 Deadlock?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, deadlock, database-deadlocks

My task is to create a deadlock with two SQL Transactions. I work in PgAdmin.
The task says:
"Create two SQL transactions that can be executed
interactively (annotate in comments in which order the transactions should be interleaved) to
create a deadlock and explain the reason of the deadlock."
I tried to create it and read about it online, but this is the only error I get when trying to make two processes go at the same time without COMMIT/ROLLBACK.
I get this error message:

```
    ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
    SQL state: 25P02
```

If that is not deadlock, can you help me make one?

http://zarez.net/?p=1069

```
    CREATE TABLE deadlock_example_table_1 (column1 int)

    CREATE TABLE deadlock_example_table_2 (column1 int)

    INSERT INTO deadlock_example_table_1 (column1)
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3
    GO

    INSERT INTO deadlock_example_table_2 (column1)
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3
    GO

    BEGIN;
    DELETE FROM deadlock_example_table_1 WHERE column1 = 2

    BEGIN;
    DELETE FROM deadlock_example_table_2 WHERE column1 = 2
```

https://medium.com/@clairesimmonds/postgresql-decoding-deadlocks-183e6a792fd3
I was thinking the output should look something like in this article.

```
    ERROR: deadlock detected
    DETAIL:  Process 16121 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 17389 of database 16390; blocked by process 15866.
    Process 15866 waits for AccessShareLock on relation 17309 of database 16390; blocked by process 16121.
    HINT:  See server log for query details.
```

Comment: Easier way is to insert 2 rows with a process 1, then update the two rows with a process 2 , do not commit, nor rollback, then update same rows in reverse order with a process 3 , the second update of process 3 should dead lock you

Comment: Can you maybe type that out? @Gar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: populate

```
INSERT INTO deadlock_example_table_1 (column1)
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3
go
commit;
```

Step 2: process 2 , update

```
 update deadlock_example_table_1 set columns1=5 where column1=1;
```

Step 3 : process 3 (another command window) update

```
 update deadlock_example_table_1 set columns1=7 where column1=2;
 update deadlock_example_table_1 set columns1=4 where column1=1;
```

This normally should get locked

step 4: return to process 2

```
 update deadlock_example_table_1 set columns1=80 where column1=2;
```

Dead lock here

Process 2 and process 3 SHOULD be on different sessions

Comment: update deadlock_example_table_1 set column1=5 
        where column1=1
         GO
I get an syntax error at or near "GO"

Comment: Sorry, fixed that

Comment: Should this answers you, please do not hesitate to accept the question as an answer.

Comment: Here are the catches : 1: do not forget to commit after the INSERT ,  2: use two different command windows (one for process 2 and one for process 3) , if you still have issues running this, please contact me via the chat system

Answer (score 0):

Must be simultaneously executed.
Open two windows and do this:
[Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MvYT.png)